# Finding Covariance (X,Y)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Two Random Variables X and Y have a joint probability density function given by:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\left(\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x}\right) & \text{, $0 < y < x <  ∞$} \\
\\
0 & \text{, elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$
Compute Cov( X, Y ):

I know that i need to calculate E(XY) and then proceed. But i am not being able to figure out the limits of the double integral. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find $\mathbb EXY$ you must calculate: $$\int\int xyf(x,y)dydx=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^xxy\frac{2e^{-2x}}{x}dydx$$

Comment: Thank You so much